# Cast binary(8) to string for concatenation

Tags: mysql

I have a column `idvisitor` in my MySQL table with type `binary(8)`.
How can I cast this to a char in order to concat it with a string?

Example:
A query returns `0x652B61CB9B4FD13B` for `idvisitor`.

When I run `concat('h', v.idvisitor)` then I get `0x68652B61CB9B4FD13B` but I need `h652b61cb9b4fd13b`

Comment: Could you use Replace for this?
REPLACE(str, find_string, replace_with)
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php

Comment: REPLACE(0x652B61CB9B4FD13B , 0x, h)

Comment: Granted that wouldn't always work in case the string contained the 0x again .. probably not due to the x but would be the main thing to consider.

Comment: no, `replace(idvisitor, '0x', 'h')` yields `0x652B61CB9B4FD13B`. I need to somehow cast it to the right type first but I don't know how. I tried casting to CHAR but that always yields NULL

Comment: Cast it as a String first ..   technically CHAR.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp

Comment: replace(CAST(idvisitor AS CHAR), '0x', 'h')  
Something like this?  I think you can cast it inline like that, but if not, just make a procedure and cast it then run that string through the replace

Comment: @easleyfixed thanks for the comments - but I found the solution in the meantime

Comment: Glad to hear it .. Converting instead of Casting since its Binary might be the best result, so good job.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the [Matomo documentation](https://matomo.org/faq/how-to/faq_158/):

`concat('h', conv(hex(idvisitor), 16, 16))`